# Can i open my own app in flutter programmatically?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I was doing a clock app on flutter, i implemented a clock, a stopwatch, a timer and an alarm

everything was going good, it works, but i just thinked that it would be better if i open the app and not just make a notification arrive, how should i do this?

Comment: have you tried using a `PendingIntent` ?

Comment: Mhh nope, can u say more please?

Comment: Here's [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808796/what-is-an-android-pendingintent) and here's [link2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent) you'll probably want to look into the [getActivity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#getActivity(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)) portion of it

Comment: Oh so i should open it from native code using a background service?

Comment: That's up to you. But for all intents and purposes, the `PendingIntent` is the cleanest programatic way to open up your app if it's been in background or not started (yet) at all. If the alarm is "making the notification appear" you can also make the app open up instead of posting the notification by using an explicit pending intent.

Comment: However, i still don't quite know how this actually applies to iOS; or how their handling would be done in Dart. I'm just covering the android part, still being somewhat fresh with flutter. So I too would be interested in whether a pending intent solves this, and works on both android and iOS. if you make it work - do post an answer please :)

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55694333/flutter-pendingintents-not-received-when-code-is-executed-through-flutter) answer suggest it should work though. Just might not be doable through only dart (i wouldn't know yet)

Comment: Ok thinking about it is better if i just use alarm manager and just schedule a timer, but, if i use runApp(App()); it does nothing and doesnt open the app, so i dont know how to do this... i searched a bit and didnt find anything about opening an app that isnt opened with flutter, i can even call a native method, but i neither know how to open the app from kotlin, any idea?

Comment: oh sure i will make a post with the answer

Comment: PendingIntent should do the trick for the android part of it. regardless of kotlin/java. How (and whether) it will work on iOS is a different story though :D 

But both java/kotlin and iOS code can call into flutter code.

Comment: try taking a look at these things: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54088421/sending-android-sms-broadcastreceiver-data-to-flutter-through-eventchannel), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64052156/how-do-you-use-receiver-broadcastreceiver-in-a-flutter-plugin), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54474802/how-to-use-setmethodcallhandler?noredirect=1&lq=1), [link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187680/how-to-call-methods-in-dart-portion-of-the-app-from-the-native-platform-using-m)